# Ragged transposition with Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a data table like this (ignoring the index):

```
group, subgroup, score 
A, B, 0
A, C, 1.5
A, A, 5
B, A, 1
B, F, 1.5
B, C, 0
C, C, 2
C, D, 3
```

I want a table like this:

```
group, subgroup w lowest score, w second lowest score, w third lowest
A, B, C, A
B, C, A, F
C, C, D, (blank)
```

How can I use Pandas to get from one to the other?

Comment: Does each subgroup occur at most once in each group, or could a single group contain multiple rows with the same subgroup?

Comment: Yes, each subgroup appears at most once within each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty compact way.  I'm over-writing the 'score' value with the rank for simplicity, but you could preserve the original score if you wanted to (it's just a little more verbose that way).

```
df['score'] = df.groupby('group')['score'].rank()
df.set_index(['group','score']).unstack()

      subgroup        
score        1  2    3
group                 
A            B  C    A
B            C  A    F
C            C  D  NaN
```

Note that this will choke on data where there is a tie for first or second.  You could get around this in a variety of ways (e.g. `rank(method='first')` would be one way, but `rank` gives you other options also).  You didn't specify that so I'm not sure how you want to handle it.

**Edit to add:**  Now that I'm looking at @JoeCondron's answer more closely I realize my approach is pretty similar but I think they are different enough that I'll leave this up for a little while at least.  In particular Joe is sorting and I am ranking which might matter in the case of how you handle a tie.

Comment: I initially thought of `rank` but have never used it and couldn't get it to work. I like this answer better. It's more compact and doesn't involve sorting the whole df which can be expensive. +1

Comment: @JoeCondron Thanks, and that is very sporting of you as our approaches are similar and yours was first.  +1 right back at you.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to introduce a column ranking the subgroups and then pivot. 
First sort by the score and do a group by transform:

```
df.sort('score', inplace=True)
ranks = ['lowest', 'second lowest', 'third lowest']
df['rank'] = df.groupby('group').subgroup.transform(lambda s: ranks[:len(s)])
```

Then pivot:

```
In [44]:    df.pivot(index='group', columns='rank', values='subgroup')

Out[44]:
rank    lowest  second lowest   third lowest
group           
A   B   C   A
B   C   A   F
C   C   D   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there may be cases where there is no '3rd lowest score', maybe we need `itertools.izip_longest` here:

```
In [85]:

from itertools import izip_longest
gby = df.groupby(['group']).agg(lambda x: tuple(x))
print pd.DataFrame(data = list(izip_longest(*map(lambda x, y: [v[1] for v in sorted(zip(y,x))], 
                                                 gby.subgroup, gby.score))),
                   columns= gby.index,
                   index = ['subgroup w lowest score', 
                            'w second lowest score', 
                            'w third lowest']).T 


      subgroup w lowest score w second lowest score w third lowest
group                                                             
A                           B                     C              A
B                           C                     A              F
C                           C                     D           None
```